# WebRequest not returning HTML

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack, webrequest

I want to load this http://www.yellowpages.ae/categories-by-alphabet/h.html url, but it returns null

In some question I have heard about adding Cookie container but it is already there in my code.

```
var MainUrl = "http://www.yellowpages.ae/categories-by-alphabet/h.html";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
web.PreRequest += request =>
{
    request.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
    return true;
};
web.CacheOnly = false;
var doc = web.Load(MainUrl);
```

the website opens perfectly fine in browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `CookieCollection` to get cookies and set `UseCookie` to `true` in `HtmlWeb`.

```
CookieCollection cookieCollection = null;
var web = new HtmlWeb
{
    //AutoDetectEncoding = true,
    UseCookies = true,
    CacheOnly = false,
    PreRequest = request =>
    {
        if (cookieCollection != null && cookieCollection.Count > 0)
            request.CookieContainer.Add(cookieCollection);

        return true;
    },
    PostResponse = (request, response) => { cookieCollection = response.Cookies; }
};

var doc = web.Load("https://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it is a cookie issue. Looks like a gzip encryption since I got nothing but gibberish when I tried to fetch the page. If it was a cookie issue the response should return an error saying so. Anyhow. Here is my solution to your problem.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.yellowpages.ae/categories-by-alphabet/h.html");
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "text/html;charset=utf-8";
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                doc.Load(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

All it does is that it decrypts/extracts the gzip message that we receive.
How did I know it was GZIP you ask? The response stream from the debugger said that the ContentEncoding was gzip.

Basically just add:

```
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

To your code and you're good.